# Secured streaming of flv files

Tags: apache-flex, flv, netstream

I want to play a flv file over http using a custom player in flex. 
The video content has to be made secure due to piracy reasons. Our idea is to encrypt the byte array of the flv files and decrypt it in the player using NetStream class in Flex.

The problem is that Netstream class requires the complete byte array to be appended using appendBytes() but th size of the file is huge so its not a valid approach.

I want to skip a few bytes in the beginning of the stream(appended at the server) and play the video.

Kindly suggest an approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how secure you want it to be. Normally just doing it over https should be good enough with some sort of authentication.  If you're really paranoid, you might want to look at Adobe's DRM solution, [Adobe Pass](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobepass/).